# параметризованный INSERT N записей

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Подскажите, в C# есть параметризованный, где можно перечислить списки параметров, а затем за кулисами при передаче параметров произойдет экранирование параметров и все такое.

А есть ли средства, что бы можно было пульнуть коллекцию в такой запрос

```
INSERT INTO T1 (F1,F2) VALUES (@F1,@F2)
```

и сгенерировалось бы:
`INSERT INTO T1 (F1,F2) VALUES (1,1),(2,2),(3,3)...(n,n)` ?

Или подобное делается только ручками?

Answer (score 6):

Можно спустить вставляемые записи в виде Table-Valued Parameter, примерно так:

Создать табличный тип для передаваемого параметра:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CategoryTableType AS TABLE  
    ( CategoryID int, CategoryName nvarchar(50) )
```

И передать из C# параметр в виде `DataTable`, `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`, или `DbDataReader`:

```
string sqlInsert = @"INSERT INTO dbo.Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName) 
SELECT nc.CategoryID, nc.CategoryName FROM @tvpNewCategories AS nc";

SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, connection);  
SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpNewCategories", addedCategories);  
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  
tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.CategoryTableType";
```

Полный пример есть в [MSDN: Table-Valued Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

Если данных много (больше 1000 строк) - лучше вставлять данные через запихнуть через bulk insert, вызовом [`SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: А без создания типа никак? Только писать самопальное решение?

Comment: @iluxa1810 без создания типа - SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer

Comment: но такое решение не универсально=( Например, в MySql такого нет и можно только через посредника в виде CSV файла вставлять. Я думал, что есть что-то универсальное.

Comment: @iluxa1810 универсальное - вставлять по одной строчке, отдельными инсертами. т.к. даже подход с  "VALUES (1,1),(2,2) " не универсален - например, не работает в SQL Server 2005.